# number theory about index

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Given the congruence $x^3 \equiv a \pmod p$, where $p \geq 5$ is a prime and $\gcd(a,p)=1$, prove the following:

- If $p \equiv1 \pmod 6$, then the congruence has either no solutions or three incongruent solutions modulo $p$
- If $p \equiv5 \pmod 6$, then the congruence has a unique solution modulo $p$

Help me...

I don't know what I learn because Prof teaches so quickly.

So I need your help to organize my thoughts.

Comment: Read [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/320910/11619) for the case $a=1$ and theory. [This](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1491103/11619) is even more relevant.

Comment: And [this recent thread](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1978934/11619) is specific to exponent $3$, but the asker there made a bit more progress themselves than you have showed.